# Knockout.js textarea binding not updating after subscribe (item selected in combo box)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I'm pretty new to this, but just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... The text-area is not getting the new value after subscribe occurs (item selected in combo-box) I'm getting data back from all my requests...  I just can't figure out if I'm not doing something in the success part of my 'subscribe' inside my viewmodel or if something is wrong with my bindings... Any help is appreciated...

```
<div style="margin-top: 100px; width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

<h2>Workflows</h2>

<select data-bind="options: Workflows, optionsText: 'Name', value: Workflow, optionsCaption: 'Choose Workflow...'">
</select>
<input data-bind="click: put" id="RunWorkflow" type="button" value="Run Workflow" />
<textarea data-bind="value: Moo" type="text" style="background-color: beige; color: black; display: block; margin-top: 20px; height: 400px; width: 80%;">
</textarea>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var WorkflowViewModel = function ()
{

    self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable("Who");
    self.Moo = ko.observable("George");

    var Workflow =
    {
        Name: self.Name,
        Moo: self.Moo
    };

    self.Workflow = ko.observable();
    self.Workflows = ko.observableArray();

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Get", "Workflow", new { httproute = "api" })',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (data)
            {
                self.Workflows(data);
            }
        });
    });

    self.Workflow.subscribe(function (WorkFlow)
    {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Get", "Workflow", new { httproute = "api" })',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { name: WorkFlow.Name },
            success: function (data)
            {
                self.Moo = data.Moo;
                self.Name = data.Name;
            }
        });
    });

};

var workflowViewModel = new WorkflowViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(workflowViewModel);
```

Comment: Oh, this may look weird since it looks like I am getting the same info in the subscribe request... It is a little different... I'm not getting Moo in the initial document.Ready since I am assuming it could be large, so I only wanted to bring it down if requested... I'm only setting Name again in the subscribe because I was tinkering trying to figure out what was wrong... Sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the value of the observable correctly. Change this:

```
self.Moo = data.Moo;
self.Name = data.Name;
```

to this:

```
self.Moo(data.Moo);
self.Name(data.Name);
```